# Maximum Entropy without the probabilities

Tags: optimization, entropy, maximum-entropy

The entropy of a distribution is defined as

$H = -\sum_{i=1}^n p_i \log(p_1)$

The principle of maximum entropy states that we should choose the distribution, subject to our constraints, that maximizes that quantity, the entropy.

An example: A 6-sided dice with expected value of 4.5 yields the probabilities.
$\{.0544, .0788, .1142, .1654, .2398, .3475\}$

My question: Let's say you are interested in a linear combination of those probabilities; for example $X=3p_3+5p_5$ Is there a way to determine the value of $X$, whose probabilities come from maximum entropy solution, without having to calculate the probabilities themselves? (The value of $H$ is also nice to have as well)

Example: Here we know that X=1.5416, which came from the Maximum Entropy solution above. Another method to get that value could be:

1. Have $3p_3+5p_5=x$ be another constraint, for some $x$
2. Solve the MaxEnt solution for $p_i$
3. Determine $H$ from $p$
4. Choose the $x$ which maximizes $H$

A chart of that procedure is below:
[image: Entropy of Dice Example]

We can see that $x$=1.5416 produces the maximum entropy with using a variable $x$ as a constraint; so without that constraint that answer would be the value of $X$ for the original problem.

However, I cheated in creating this chart: I solved for the probabilities at each point to plot the value of $H$ at each point, all as a function of $x$. Is there a way to determine the $\{X,H\}$ pair without having to solve for the probabilities at any point?

The example here was for a six-sided dice, our problem is infinite and grid of probabilities and we are finding ourselves having to calculate all the $p$'s to determine the value of $X$ of interest, when the values of individual probabilities themselves are not of interest and are deleted as soon as $X$ is determined.